# Using a font and string as a Drawable

Tags: android, fonts, android-drawable

In the spirit of simple vector images on Android that always look sharp, I was wondering if I can't use custom font paired with a string (or a character) as a `Drawable`.

For instance, if I wanted to use a Webdings character as the drawable on a `Button`, how would I do this?

I want the best font size to be selected (using `dip` or `sp`) so that I get no distortion on the image.

Do you have any ideas how I can accomplish this goal?

Thanks!

Comment: If that's what you want, why not use a text label on the button?  Which is what a default button has (ImageButton is the one that uses an image).

Comment: It really needs to be a drawable.  What if I wanted to display an icon in the drawableLeft portion of an EditText?  Same problem...

Comment: This is a related issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8831182/602245

Comment: Yeah it is related, but it is not the same: Brett wants something that  adjusts font size and so on.  It is entirely possible: Simply a matter of Programming.  Extending Drawable in this way, though, is going to be a fair amount of work...

Comment: Check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/40692513/4291698

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check out my library [IconicTextView](https://github.com/atermenji/IconicTextView)
It allows to use several iconic fonts to display vector images.
Currently a subclass of TextView is used to display them but I'm working on rewriting it to use custom Drawable.
The main issue here is selecting the best font size, I'm trying to find a way to auto adjust font size.

Comment: The ability to automatically adjust font size would be critical to me here, thanks!

Comment: Hi @Brett! I've updated the library. Now there is a class called IconicFontDrawable (https://github.com/atermenji/IconicTextView/blob/master/library/src/com/atermenji/android/iconictextview/IconicFontDrawable.java). It draws an icon from custom iconic font and automatically adjusts text size to container bounds.