# How to use icon from font file as a drawable in Android

Tags: android, fonts, android-actionbar, typeface

I have a font file whose icons I am using in layout files via a Custom TextView.

I created a Custom Class :
    **class CustomFontTextView extends TextView**

say, icon is there in Font file Sample.ttf as string resource :

```
<string name="icon">&#xe038;</string>
```

In layouts, I can use it as :

```
<com.sec.mywash.views.CustomFontTextView
custom:custom_typeface="sample_font"
 android:text="@string/icon"/>.
```

However , my **requirement is to change the Home up button in action bar that we set in style.xml** as item:

```
<item "android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/....</item>
```

How to use the **icon image from font file in style.xml which takes drawable.**

Comment: Are you trying to use .ttf as drawable ? between check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15098468/using-a-font-and-string-as-a-drawable

Comment: I am trying to use an icon from .ttf as a drawable instead of custom textview.

Comment: Create a separate drawable. Tomorrow your requirements could change and this font would be removed...

Comment: @JaiprakashSoni Yes I want similar thing but I can't use any library for this.

Comment: @ViktorYakunin you mean create a custom drawable ? If so , how to make custom drawable from .ttf ?

Comment: don't make custom drawable from .ttf . just create the icon you need in png format and use it.

Comment: Possible Workaround: You could draw the text on a bitmap and use that bitmap as your drawable.

Comment: @Surbhi there are a lot ways to do that, for example you can use the font for some image editor and create the set of image resources. this might be helpful https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html

Comment: @ViktorYakunin The reason for using `TTF` instead of an image is, you don't need to create a separate image for each icon and each size, By using a font, size of your apk drops drastically specially if you are using a android system font.

Answer (score 6):

You can create your own drawable class for doing this, something like this

```
/** Embed an icon into a Drawable that can be used as TextView icons, or ActionBar icons.
 *
 * new IconDrawable(context, IconValue.icon_star)
 *           .colorRes(R.color.white)
 *           .actionBarSize();
 * 
 * If you don't set the size of the drawable, it will use the size
 * that is given to him. Note that in an ActionBar, if you don't
 * set the size explicitly it uses 0, so please use actionBarSize().
 */

public class FontIconDrawable extends Drawable {

public static int ANDROID_ACTIONBAR_ICON_SIZE_DP = 24;

private final Context context;

private final String icon;

private TextPaint paint;

private int size = -1;

private int alpha = 255;

/**
 * Create an IconDrawable.
 *
 * @param context Your activity or application context.
 * @param icon    The icon you want this drawable to display.
 */
public FontIconDrawable(Context context, String icon, Typeface typeface) {
    this.context = context;
    this.icon = icon;
    paint = new TextPaint();
    paint.setTypeface(typeface);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    paint.setUnderlineText(false);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
}

/**
 * Set the size of this icon to the standard Android ActionBar.
 *
 * @return The current IconDrawable for chaining.
 */
public FontIconDrawable actionBarSize() {
    return sizeDp(ANDROID_ACTIONBAR_ICON_SIZE_DP);
}

/**
 * Set the size of the drawable.
 *
 * @param dimenRes The dimension resource.
 * @return The current IconDrawable for chaining.
 */
public FontIconDrawable sizeRes(int dimenRes) {
    return sizePx(context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(dimenRes));
}

/**
 * Set the size of the drawable.
 *
 * @param size The size in density-independent pixels (dp).
 * @return The current IconDrawable for chaining.
 */
public FontIconDrawable sizeDp(int size) {
    return sizePx(dpToPx(context.getResources(), size));
}

/**
 * Dp to px.
 *
 * @param res the res
 * @param dp  the dp
 * @return the int
 */
public static int dpToPx(Resources res, int dp) {
    return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp,
            res.getDisplayMetrics());
}

/**
 * Set the size of the drawable.
 *
 * @param size The size in pixels (px).
 * @return The current IconDrawable for chaining.
 */
public FontIconDrawable sizePx(int size) {
    this.size = size;
    setBounds(0, 0, size, size);
    invalidateSelf();
    return this;
}

/**
 * Set the color of the drawable.
 *
 * @param color The color, usually from android.graphics.Color or 0xFF012345.
 * @return The current IconDrawable for chaining.
 */
public FontIconDrawable color(int color) {
    paint.setColor(color);
    invalidateSelf();
    return this;
}

/**
 * Set the color of the drawable.
 *
 * @param colorRes The color resource, from your R file.
 * @return The current IconDrawable for chaining.
 */
public FontIconDrawable colorRes(int colorRes) {
    paint.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(colorRes));
    invalidateSelf();
    return this;
}

/**
 * Set the alpha of this drawable.
 *
 * @param alpha The alpha, between 0 (transparent) and 255 (opaque).
 * @return The current IconDrawable for chaining.
 */
public FontIconDrawable alpha(int alpha) {
    setAlpha(alpha);
    invalidateSelf();
    return this;
}

@Override
public int getIntrinsicHeight() {
    return size;
}

@Override
public int getIntrinsicWidth() {
    return size;
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    paint.setTextSize(getBounds().height());
    Rect textBounds = new Rect();
    String textValue = icon;
    paint.getTextBounds(textValue, 0, 1, textBounds);
    float textBottom = (getBounds().height() - textBounds.height()) / 2f + textBounds.height() - textBounds.bottom;
    canvas.drawText(textValue, getBounds().width() / 2f, textBottom, paint);
}

@Override
public boolean isStateful() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean setState(int[] stateSet) {
    int oldValue = paint.getAlpha();
    int newValue = isEnabled(stateSet) ? alpha : alpha / 2;
    paint.setAlpha(newValue);
    return oldValue != newValue;
}

/**
 * Checks if is enabled.
 *
 * @param stateSet the state set
 * @return true, if is enabled
 */
public static boolean isEnabled(int[] stateSet) {
    for (int state : stateSet)
        if (state == android.R.attr.state_enabled)
            return true;
    return false;
}

@Override
public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
    this.alpha = alpha;
    paint.setAlpha(alpha);
}

@Override
public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
    paint.setColorFilter(cf);
}

@Override
public void clearColorFilter() {
    paint.setColorFilter(null);
}

@Override
public int getOpacity() {
    return PixelFormat.OPAQUE;
}

/**
 * Sets paint style.
 *
 * @param style to be applied
 */
public void setStyle(Paint.Style style) {
    paint.setStyle(style);
}
}
```

Comment: How to use this code with drawer icons or as OP asking in action bar?

Comment: You can do it like this
in your onCreateOptionsMenu()
MenuItem profileItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_profile);
Drawable profileDrawable = new FontIconDrawable(context, icon, getFontIconTypeface(context)).actionBarSize();
profileItem.setIcon(profileDrawable);

public static Typeface getFontIconTypeface(Context context) {
        return Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "icons.ttf");
    }

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case its not possible to change Home up button icon via xml...you are using an iconFont, so your icon is actually a text and to display those icons you need your CustomTextView or any View, which extends the TextView. android:homeAsUpIndicator requires drawable. Possible solution could be: to have this special icon in drawable folder.