# Can we add text to a drawable?

Tags: java, android, drawable

I want to create a drawable which looks like this.

[image]   and    [image]

I know how to create the image background but even after searching, I am unable to find how to give text to that drawable file. Is there any way that the drawable file is exactly same containing the text as well?

I cant use textview because its a tab and I need drawables to set as background resource (thats what I know, please correct me if I am wrong.). So I want a drawable file which I can set as background.

[image]

Comment: take look on this tutorial 
http://android-dev-tips-and-tricks.blogspot.com/2012/08/xml-drawables-part-i.html
feed me back

Comment: and this 
http://sriramramani.wordpress.com/2013/01/15/compound-drawables/

Comment: can you post some codes you tried, since actually we can add TEXT to Drawable by adding both drawable and text tpo canvas

Comment: What I have tried is a png format image as I have pasted here. Since this makes the app apk bigger, I was thinking to use a drawable. So I am asking if we can add text to drawables.

Comment: Use two background as above images with bottom cyan color focus and without cyan color focus and text according in onClick event

Comment: All I see there are black rectangles with text in them and the one on the left has a horizontal blue bar at the bottom. Have you tried simply using `TextViews` and adding the blue bar as a bottom drawable?

Comment: No I cant use textviews, because I have to set that drawable as tab background. See updated ques.

Comment: If they're ActionBar tabs then this is done for you.

Comment: No its not action bar.. Tab widget tab host.. Can we add text to tab widget item via code.?

Comment: Yes - you can add text, icon or both and the `TabHost` will also provide a drawable to indicate it has been selected.

Comment: Can you please show some example to show that the selected one is highlighted in the same way and the text to the item (Like FlashLight Torch here) is added from the code. Please post that as an answer and I will accept it.. Thanx a lot..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that.

**See the post** -

[How to put text in a drawable ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972445/how-to-put-text-in-a-drawable)

Basically, you have to extend the class `Drawable` and set the canvas to draw the text
to a drawable.

As you override the `draw` method, it will take the canvas and draw the text on defined locations.

There are many methods available for `Canvas`.

As explained in a graphics doc. -

> The Canvas class has its own set of drawing methods that you can use,
>   like drawBitmap(...), drawRect(...), drawText(...), and many more.
>   Other classes that you might use also have draw() methods. For
>   example, you'll probably have some Drawable objects that you want to
>   put on the Canvas. Drawable has its own draw() method that takes your
>   Canvas as an argument.

Drawing text will be just like the following -

```
canvas.drawText("Front Screen Torch", 30, 48, paint);
```

To get the actual color directly from resources use -

```
paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
```

See [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) for more.

Answer (score 0):

YES you can and Much More With this control over canvas ,I use This alot to To get Full control over the drawable

```
public static Drawable getTextDrawable(@ColorInt int iColor) {
 Shape shape = new Shape(){

        @Override
        public void draw(Canvas canvas, Paint paint)
        {
            paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);

            paint.setTextSize(100);

            int radii = dpToPx(3);

            canvas.drawText("Hello Canvas", canvas.getWidth() - 150, canvas.getHeight() / 2, paint);

            canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth() - radii * 2, canvas.getHeight() /2 - radii, radii, paint);
        }
    };
    shape.getHeight();

    Drawable drawable = new ShapeDrawable(shape);

    return drawable;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

> Can we add text to a drawable ?

No, you can't.

Alternate option for this is to create a drawable with Text.

Comment: What is the meaning of "Alternate option for this is to create a drawable with Text.".?

Comment: means just directly have a image which has text init. It will avoid the coding time.

Comment: of course you can: just extend BitmapDrawable and. override draw method

Comment: Ya but Its increasing the App size as I have to use 2 images for each tab that means around a dozen of images in my drawables.

Comment: @AkshatJaiswal No, you dont have to keep two images: see my comment above